# MATLAB "echo on" inside a function. Is it possible?

Tags: matlab

I read [in the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/echo.html) that I can use the statement `echo on;` to have MATLAB print the statements it executes. However, I am having difficulties making this work inside a function.

For example:

```
function do_something(foo)

a   = 2;
echo on;
foo = foo+1;
disp('This is a test');
foo = foo+3;

end
```

If I call `do_something(foo)` from the command window, I was expecting to see something like:

```
foo = foo+1;
disp('This is a test');
This is a test
foo = foo+3;
```

However, in the example above, all MATLAB prints is:

```
this is a test
```

which is not what I was expecting.

## Update

As @Phonon explains below, `echo on` is only for scripts (sorry I missed that!). However, I read in the documentation that I can activate `echo` for a given function as follows:

```
echo fcnname on
```

So my question now is, is there a way to activate echo for a function using some variation of the syntax above so that I do this (call `echo`) **inside a function**? (the variable that holds the function name in this case would be provided by [`mfilename`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mfilename.html))

## Update 2:

As far as I understand it is **not** possible to activate `echo` for a particular function inside the actual function. Among other things, it seems that MATLAB needs to know beforehand if the function has to run in "echo mode" to avoid using **JIT**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Matlab documentation, i.e. `help echo`,

> `ECHO ON` turns on echoing of commands inside *Script-files*.

It will not work inside functions. To make it work for functions, according to that same help file,

> `ECHO ON ALL` turns on the echoing of commands inside any Function-files that are currently in memory (i.e., the functions returned by `INMEM`).
>
> `ECHO OFF ALL` turns them all off.

**Update**:

In order to find which function you're in currently, the best way I see of doing it is by calling `dbstack`. Goes somewhat as follows:

```
[S,I] = dbstack;
funcName = S.name;
```

Comment: Thanks Phonon. Do you know how can I activate "echo on" inside a function using a generic statement (non-funcion specific statement), e.g. maybe using `mfilename`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. `echo on all` will work for everything, it's not specific to a given function. If you only want it to work for a certain function, but not others you have to turn it off before you call anything from your function.

Comment: Thanks @Phonon. I have updated the original question with an update section that explains what I am trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something along the lines of what @Ben Voigt provided, but your answer was the first one to address my original actual problem, so I'll accept it.

Comment: I just wrote a final update on the original post. I think MATLAB needs to know beforehand if the function will run in "echo mode", so activating `echo` inside the function (which was the original purpose of the question) will not work.

Comment: Feel free to accept any answer you consider to be correct. The idea is to build up a good problem-solution base.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo fcnname on
```

is the same as

```
echo('fcnname','on');
```

Using the function call syntax, you can pass a variable instead:

```
echo(found_found, 'on');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think echo on works inside a function. You can always turn on echo outside of the function though using the following method:

```
foo = 1;
echo do_something on;
do_something(foo);
echo do_something off;
```

The only reason not to use that is if you want just a part of your function to be displayed and not all the lines. If you insist on seeing the line and the result of a specific part of your function, a *crude way* of doing this for a limited number of lines would be:

```
s = {'foo = 1;'
     'foo = foo+1;'
     'disp(''This is a test'');'
     'foo = foo+3;'
     'foo'
    };
for i = 1:numel(s)
   disp(s{i}); eval(s{i});
end
```

Will display:

```
foo = 1;
foo = foo+1;
disp('This is a test');
This is a test
foo = foo+3;
foo

foo =

     5
```

I have to also add that I probably would not use a method like this for debugging. There are better ways to figure out what is happening inside a function.